# Fatal error after Magento installation 'undefined method ProductExtension::setStockItem()'

Tags: magento2, installation, code-generation, extension-attributes

When I run Magento I get

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method
>   Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductExtension::setStockItem() in
>   /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/module-catalog-inventory/Model/Plugin/AfterProductLoad.php
>   on line 47

Please help

Answer (score 3):

The problem seems to be that `ProductExtension` is not generated (this is auto-generated class).

If running Magento in `production` or `default` mode, code generation on-fly is disabled and you need to run compiler after installation, execute `<project_root>/bin/magento setup:di:compile` as described in [Magento dev docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-compiler.html).

If running Magento in `developer` mode, make sure `var/generation` directory is writable.

Answer (score 1):

try install

```
apt-get install php7.2-bcmath
```